# Default Values for PhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I do NOT set any values for the following, what are the default values in Swift 3, SpriteKit?

```
self.physicsBody?.restitution 
self.physicsBody?.friction 
self.physicsBody?.linearDamping
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all those values at the SKPhysicsBody API:

restitution = 0.2
friction = Defaults to 0.2
linearDamping = 0.1

Comment: Cheers :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Restitution from the [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520447-restitution)

> This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body
>   loses when it bounces off another object. The property must be a value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0. **The default value is 0.2.**

Friction from the [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519840-friction)

> This property is used to apply a frictional force to physics bodies in
>   contact with this physics body. The property must be a value between
>   0.0 and 1.0. **The default value is 0.2.**

Linear Dampening from the [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519796-lineardamping)

> This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the
>   body. The property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0. **The default
>   value is 0.1.** If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is applied to the
>   object.

Comment: Thank you also :D

Comment: @Questions No prob.